# Path pom.xml in local .m2 repo in plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, artifacts

I try to make some maven plugin. I need to get path for artifact and pom.xml just after install phase. I got artifact path like this:

D:\Work\test\mvn\moduleFirst\target\first-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

And pom.xml path like this:

D:\Work\test\mvn\moduleFirst\pom.xml

But if in pom.xml package are set "pom", then I got artifact path like this:

C:\Users\user.m2\repository\com\test\mvn\1.0-SNAPSHOT\mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

And pom.xml:

D:\Work\test\mvn\pom.xml

I'd like get all path from .m2 local repo. How it possible?

I make follow code:

```
...
    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${project.file}"
     */
    private File pomFile;
...
    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${project.artifact}"
     */
    private Artifact artifact;
...
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
...
        getLog().info("POM file " + pomFile.getAbsolutePath());
        getLog().info("Artifact " + artifact.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
...
    /**
     * @parameter expression="${localRepository}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    protected ArtifactRepository localRepository;
...
    protected String getLocalRepoFile(Artifact artifact) {
        File file = new File(localRepository.getBasedir(), localRepository.pathOf(artifact));
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
...
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
...
getLog().info("Artifact " + getLocalRepoFile(artifact));
...
    }
```

Thanks to maven-install-plugin :)